# Is it possible to use a pointer as a template argument?

Tags: c++, templates, types, c++17

Since it's possible to use primitive types as template arguments, I was wondering if it was possible for a pointer type?

In my mind it makes no sense since a fixed pointer can't exist, so the compiler shouldn't be able to construct the assembly for such templates but I might be surprised!

Example:

```cpp
template <FILE *stream = stdout>
class A;
```

Comment: At the very least you can provide `nullptr` as a pointer template argument. This is a real use case with `std::enable_if`.

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13220502/uses-of-pointers-non-type-template-parameters